# Docker Container not connecting through IP on ec2

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, docker-container

I have assigned my aws ip to my docker docker container with following command
`$ docker network create --driver bridge --subnet <ip>/16 --gateway <ip> docker-network`
It is showing the port assigned to it but not connecting with it.[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aedpF.png)

Comment: When I try to access it through browser, it shows "This site cannot be reached, address refused to connect"

Comment: Not sure what you are doing. Please explain in details.

Comment: I ran a docker container in ec2 of which screenshot is added, Then I assigned my public address to that container, but when I try to access the container through the web browser, it displays error "This site cannot be reached, refused to connect"

Comment: Have you opened port 80 in the instance's security group?

Comment: I have set on All Traffic in my instance security group

Comment: Ok I have removed my containers set my security group to all ... Can you help me step by step, like 1. Run container from image, 2. configure my public ip with that container, 3. acces it from browser

Comment: did you later fix this? if so, please help!!!